# Is there a query for this?

Tags: mysql

Im making a system for a school and I have this mySQL tables. The names are self explanatory:

```
student: id name course_id
course: id name
subject: id name
subject_course: id subject_id course_id
grade: id type grade
grade_type: id name
```

I need to check if every student of a certain course has a grade of type X on every subject that is related with that course.
Let's say grade_type = 'written test'. So I need to check if every student of 1st grade has a grade on the written test on EVERY subject related to first grade (example: math, spanish, history, etc). If yes, I do some stuff. If not, another.

Is there a query that can check that? I was thinking on check student by student but I think is less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This schema doesn't seem to make sense.

Why would course_id be field on student table?  My guess is you need a `student_course` table to represent a many-to-many relationship between students and courses here.

Also, the `grade_type` table seems kind of trivial and extra overhead with little value.  Could `type` not just be an enum on `grade` table?

Comment: grade_type has a CRUD for the school to add new kinds of types. 
For the course_id, it can be in a table like student_course but it does not harm to keep it there. It makes other tasks easier.

Comment: @DavidTG Would a student never expect to be related to more than one course?